# Javascript function in background.js not being called at all using message passing.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is my popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title> Chrome Extension</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      </head>
      <body id="container">
        <div id="left">
          <form>
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="query" />
            <button id="openBackgroundWindow">Open background window</button>
          </div>
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="Search" alt="Loading" />
        </form>
        <!-- rest of the code will follow this -->
        <!-- other code above -->
      <div id="results">
        <ul id="results-list">
          <!-- this gets populated -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end #left -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

This is my popup.js:

```
$("#openBackgroundWindow").click(function(){

    login();
     chrome.extension.sendRequest({ msg: "login" });

});

function openNextPage(){  
 var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().openNextPage();
}  

function pageRender(){
console.log("no user")
  if (localStorage.getItem("username") == null){
    console.log("no user")
  }

    function codeAddress() {
        document.getElementById('button').style.visibility='hidden'; 
    }

}

function login(){

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/login", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // JSON.parse does not evaluate the attacker's scripts.
    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  }
}

xhr.send();
}
```

This is my background.js:

```
function login(){

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/login", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // JSON.parse does not evaluate the attacker's scripts.
    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  }
}

xhr.send();
}


chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        print "hello";
        if(request.msg == "login") login();
    }
);
```

Neither login() function from background.js is being called nor the login function in the popup.js is being called. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me

Use `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>`

instead of

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive. Download min js and have it in your package

More over instead of

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
```

<strike>print "hello";</strike>

```
        if(request.msg == "login") login();
    }
);
```

Use

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){

console.log("hello");

        if(request.msg == "login") login();
    }
);
```

Make sure you have declared

```
 "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  }
```

in your manifest file

**My Final Working Versions**

***manifest.json***

```
 {
  "name": "Demo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This is a demo",
  "browser_action":{
  "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  }
  }
```

***Popup.js***

```
function login(){
alert("function called");
chrome.extension.sendRequest({ msg: "login" });
}

$(document).ready(function (){
console.log("Inside");
$("#openBackgroundWindow").click(login);
});
```

***popup.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title> Chrome Extension</title>
          <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />-->
      </head>
      <body id="container">
        <div id="left">
          <form>
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="query" />
            <button id="openBackgroundWindow">Open background window</button>
          </div>
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="Search" alt="Loading" />
        </form>
        <!-- rest of the code will follow this -->
        <!-- other code above -->
      <div id="results">
        <ul id="results-list">
          <!-- this gets populated -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end #left -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

***Background.js***

```
function login_br(){

alert("function called");
}


chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        console.log("hello");
        if(request.msg == "login") login_br();
    }
);
```

It worked perfectly with above code, let me know if you still have issues

Answer (score 1):

Although Sudarshan is completely right about providing your own jQuery lib there is a way to load jQuery from Google's CDN. You have to add the following content security rule to your manifest file.

```js
    ...
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
    ...
```

For more information read the [official Chrome documentation on Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) and especially follow the links there to the [CSP specification](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html#syntax).